# Ugly control over the control placing possibility

Tags: wpf, controls, stackpanel, dockpanel

I have the dock panel, two buttons on which docked to left and right corners and a stackpanel with controls located on it. I need to put a part of left and right sides of the stackpanel under this two docked buttons, and set to the first child of the stackpanel some shift from border. Is this possible????

Comment: You can achieve almost anything you want in terms of layout with WPF, can you post us the xaml you have already, its hard to tell exactly what you mean here. Maybe a grid would be more suitable than a stackpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to place all your controls in a `Canvas` instead of a `DockPanel`, and use `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Left`, and `Canvas.ZIndex to position your controls.

A different way would be to use `RenderTransforms` to adjust the element positioning at runtime.